# Search for all blog posts created on a given day

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My blog posts have a `created_at` datetime attribute.

How would I use `Blog.find` to retrieve all blog posts created on a given day (say 1/1/2009) ignoring the time on that day they were created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be pretty close.

```
d = DateTime.new(2009, 1, 1)
Blog.find(:all, :conditions => [ "created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", d.beginning_of_day, d.tomorrow.beginning_of_day ])
```